# serial construct in openacc, fortran

Tags: fortran, gpu, hpc, openacc, pgi

I have the following serial part of a FORTRAN code which should be executed
sequentially.

```
c$acc  serial 
       nppn1=0
c
       do 1200 ippas=1,50
c
       nppn0=nppn1+1
       nppn1=lppas(ippas)
c
c     -----did we complete the passes ?
c
       if(nppn1.eq.0)                                          goto 1201
c
c     -----do we have any ?
c
       if(nppn0.gt.nppn1)                                      goto 1199
c
c     -----loop over the receiving points
c
c$acc  loop seq 
       do 1400 ippne=nppn0,nppn1
c
c     -----points
c
       ipoin=bppni(1,ippne)
       jpoin=bppni(2,ippne)
c
c     -----variables 1-nunkp
c
c$acc  loop seq
       do 1410 iva=1,nunkp
       unkno(iva,ipoin)=unkno(iva,jpoin)+bppnr(iva,ippne)
 1410 continue
c
c     ----end of loop over the receiving points
c     
 1400 continue

c
c
c     ----end of loop over the passes
c     
 1199 continue
 1200 continue
 1201 continue
c$acc  end serial
```

The results obtained using the PGI compiler with the OpenACC directives
deactivated look like,

```
            ipoin        jpoin         unkno(iva,ipoin)   unkno(iva,jpoin)
before loop 160215       160165       100.3518075025082   100.3517910648527      
 after loop 160215       160165       100.3517910648527   100.3517910648527        
before loop 160165       157415       100.3517910648527   100.3517910648527         
 after loop 160165       157415       100.3517910648527   100.3517910648527
```

which is the expected behavior. However, when OpenAcc directives are activated 
the values are not updated.

```
             ipoin     jpoin    unkno(iva,ipoin)           unkno(iva,jpoin)
before loop  160215    160165   100.3518075025082         100.3517910648527     
after  loop  160215    160165   100.3518075025082         100.3517910648527
```

When compiling, the PGI compiler says the following:

```
   2552, Accelerator serial kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
       2556, !$acc do seq
       2588, !$acc do seq
       2603, !$acc do seq
   2552, Generating implicit copyin(bppnr(:nunkp,:),bppni(:2,:),lppas(:))
         Generating implicit copy(unkno(:nunkp,:))
```

So, I don't know what is happening here and how I can solve this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. The code is horribly messy with all those gotos. It would make a very good sense to refactor it (with good unit tests) befor attempting any OpenACC with that. It likely that a full compilable [mcve] will be necessary.

Comment: If you can provide a reproducing example, that would be helpful since there's not enough information to determine the issue.  The compiler feedback messages all look fine, though if you have a higher level data region, one possible cause is that you aren't copying back the results.